# Bootstrap3 datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, datepicker

Refering to the docs here:
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/

1) I am trying to set the default date so that it reads todays date in the input box.
2) I would like to get the selected date in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I instantiate the datepicker like this:

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: 'today',
    todayBtn: true,
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

So far I have tried

```
1)  $('.input-group.date').val($('.input-group.date').datepicker("getDate"));
This doesn't do anything.
2)  console.log ($('.input-group.date').datepicker("getDate"));
This returns: Sat Feb 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) instead of 02/08/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your first try didnt do anything is, because the getDate returns selected date. If you call it before selecting a date it returns empty. And To answer your second problem it should be

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString()
```

You get the date and parse it. Look here for more : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

To get the todays date and set it to datepicker:

var d = new Date();
$('.input-group.date').datepicker('setDate',d);

Comment: Thanks. I tried entering your solution but got this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toLocaleDateString'. The start date is set when its initialized so I thought I could get the get from there.

Comment: If you copy pasted it thats the problem, since I forget to add . to input-group.date to select it as class. I suggest you to give an id to input, therefore easily access it.

I edited the answer

Comment: ah yes that was it, I prefer IDs too. Thanks. Do you have a way to populate the input text value on load with the users date?

Comment: Bingo that's it! Thank you so much! I feel lazy now, because I should have been able to figure that out. You could have hinted like, maybe try setDate. Anyways, that is awesome glad to get moving forward again.